# PBS Professional hook not updating Priority

Tags: python-2.7, hook, pbs

I am trying to implement a hook to determine a job's priority upon entering the queue.

The hook is enabled, imported, and event type is "queuejob", so it is in place (like other hooks we have enabled).  This hook however does not seem to alter a job's priority as I am expecting.

Here is a simplified example of how I'm trying to alter the Priority for a job:

```
import pbs

try:

   e=pbs.event()
   j=e.job

   if j.server == 'myserver':

      j.Priority = j.Priority + 50
      e.accept()

except SystemExit:
   pass
```

Whenever I submit a job after importing this hook, I run the 'qstat -f' on my job, the Priority is always 0, whether I set it to another value in my qsub script or leave it to the default.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I discovered:

It appears that PBS does not like using j.Priority in a calculation and assignment, so I had to use another internal variable (which was fine since I had one already for something else)

i.e.:

```
 j.Priority = High_Priority 

 if pbs.server() == 'myserver'
    j.Priority = High_Priority + 50
```

Also, (as can be seen in the last example), j.server should actually be pbs.server().